# Jmeter add user

Tags: jmeter, swagger

Hi im new to jmeter and my task is to add new http request https://bookstore.toolsqa.com/Account/v1/User
and add user

```
    {
  "userName": "user",
  "password": "password123"
}
```

im using this body from https://demoqa.com/swagger/#/Account/AccountV1UserPost but it's still failing.

Comment: show more details, maybe you are missing HTTP Header with Content-Type application/json

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all add [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configure it to send [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of `application/json`
2. Add [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree), it allows you to see response details, it should give you much more info that your "fails"

When I tried to execute your request and yes, it "failed" with:

```
{"code":"1300","message":"Passwords must have at least one non alphanumeric character, one digit ('0'-'9'), one uppercase ('A'-'Z'), one lowercase ('a'-'z'), one special character and Password must be eight characters or longer."}
```

When I add a "one uppercase" and a "one non alphanumeric" character, like `!` to the password field it works normally (assuming that there is no user with this username)

Demo:

[image]

More information: [REST API Testing - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right)